# Retrofit generic service call with Single methods

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have lot of Single return methods from retrofit API call like below;

```
@GET("api/parametre/kitaptur/liste")
fun getKitapTurListe():Single<ArrayList<KitapturModel>>;
```

In viewmodel I am calling this service with CompositeDisposable by adding service api call method like this;

```
 disposible.add(
            parametreService.kitapTurKaydet(json)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<ResponseStatusModel>(){
                        override fun onSuccess(response: ResponseStatusModel) {
                            parametreEklemeError.value = false;
                            parametreEklemeLoading.value = false;
                            parametreEklemeResponse.value = response;
                            customSharedPreferences.removeFromSharedPreferences(PARAM_KITAPTUR_DB_KEY);
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            parametreEklemeError.value = true;
                            parametreEklemeLoading.value = false;
                        }
                    }));
```

Every time I am writing this disposable adding . But I have to call my services with a generic method like [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/coroutines-retrofit-and-a-nice-way-to-handle-responses-769e013ee6ef). How can I convert safeCall method for single api calls in my base view model.

Answer (score 0):

Your safeCall function needs to create a `DisposableSingleObserver` that calls the corresponding functions of the passed in `DisposableSingleObserver` plus whatever you want it to do for all.

```
//Your safeCall function should create one of these
DisposableSingleObserver<T>() {
    override fun onSuccess(result: T) {
        yourDisposableSingleObserver.onSuccess(result)
    }
    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        yourDisposableSingleObserver.onError(e)
        parseError(e)
    }
}
```

So now your call will look like this

```
 disposible.add(
            parametreService.kitapTurKaydet(json)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(safeCall(object : DisposableSingleObserver<ResponseStatusModel>(){ //notice the call to safeCall
                        override fun onSuccess(response: ResponseStatusModel) {
                            parametreEklemeError.value = false;
                            parametreEklemeLoading.value = false;
                            parametreEklemeResponse.value = response;
                            customSharedPreferences.removeFromSharedPreferences(PARAM_KITAPTUR_DB_KEY);
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            parametreEklemeError.value = true;
                            parametreEklemeLoading.value = false;
                        }));
```